# Cómo capturar un refcursor en una Lista genérica o DataTable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, postgresql

Estoy Creando una función que me devuelva un refcursor, pero cada vez que intento capturarlo en un Datatable o una lista genérica me sale

> ```
> <unnamed portal n>
> ```

Mi código:

```cs
cmd = new NpgsqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = cnx;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text; 
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT public.listado_alumnos"; 
//funcion NpgsqlParameter 
prm_estado = cmd.Parameters.Add("@pi_estado", NpgsqlDbType.Char); prm_estado.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input; 
prm_estado.Value = estadoCliente; 
NpgsqlDataReader drd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

¿Podrían ayudarme por favor?

Comment: ingresa el codigo que estas probando

Comment: cmd = new NpgsqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = cnx;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT public.listado_alumnos"; //funcion

NpgsqlParameter prm_estado = cmd.Parameters.Add("@pi_estado", NpgsqlDbType.Char);
prm_estado.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
prm_estado.Value = estadoCliente;

NpgsqlDataReader drd = cmd.ExecuteReader();

Y me retorna unnamed portal 1

Answer (score 0):

Ese  es el nombre del cursor. Creo que lo que necesitas es crear una función que devuelva el result set.

Mira el siguiente tutorial, creo que es lo que estás buscando.

http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/how-to/return_result_set_from_stored_procedure